# Browser Compatibility issues with ImageMapster 1.2.6

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, imagemapster

I am trying to create mouse-over popup bubbles on each image-mapped area. But ImageMapster 1.2.6 seems to work only on IE8, Firefox, Chrome but does not work in IE8-Compatibility mode or IE7.

The javascript shows an error: 'null' is null or not an object

If anyone has ever faced this, please let me know the link to that discussion or please help me out!

Is there anyway to force the page to open in IE8 mode (instead or Compat mode)? ....

Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you provide a link to a page showing this problem, or even better, a jsfiddle.net example that isolates just the code where this problem occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question...
On digging and debugging, I came across the correct line in the javascript file at which the object is null and simply included a code to avoid null value.
For eg:

```
if(text != null)
{
  Enter your code....
}
else
{
arr=0;
}
return arr;
```